# Effort to write a thread-safe C++ wrapper of C API

Tags: c++, thread-safety, wrapper

I am writing a 'thread-safe' C++ wrapper of C API, while the API itself is NOT internally thread safe. I have tried to use RAII.

I would like to know, is my implementation correct? and whether it is thread safe. I appreciate any comments on my code. Thanks in advance!

The C API to be wrapped is as follows,

```
 /* an data structure which represents a connection proxy to the logger: */
struct cLog_Logger;

/* connect the logger, and returns a handle to it: */
cLog_Logger* cLog_connect();

/* appends a zero terminated string to the log: */
void cLog_write(cLog_Logger* logger, const char* message);

/* closes the connection with the logger: */
void cLog_close(cLog_Logger* logger);
```

My implementation of the wrapper is as follows:

```
    class LoggerWrapper{

    public:
        LoggerWrapper(){              //constructor
            cLog= cLog_connect();
        }

        void log(const std::string &message){    //entry point
            cLog_write(cLog, message);
            cLog_close(cLog);
            }

        ~LoggerWrapper(){        //destructor
            delete cLog;
        }
    protected:
         cLog_Logger *cLog;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where are the threads?

Comment: @Ajay, Threads are everywhere outside wrapper:)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change the implementation like this:

```
class LoggerWrapper{

public:
    LoggerWrapper(){              //constructor
        cLog= cLog_connect();
    }

    void log(const std::string &message){    //entry point
        cLog_write(cLog, message);
        }

    ~LoggerWrapper(){        //destructor
        cLog_close(cLog);
        delete cLog;
    }
protected:
     cLog_Logger *cLog;
} ;
```

This allows you to write code like this:

```
LoggerWrapper logger ;
logger.log("Something") ;
logger.log("Something else) ;
```

so make more than one log with the same object; otherwise the first call closes the logger and the object is useless. Is this what you want?

Then there is the second question: what do you mean by thread safety? Do you want to make logs on the same object from different threads?

Then you can add a mutex and a lock guard inside log function like this:

```
class LoggerWrapper{

public:
    LoggerWrapper(){              //constructor
        cLog= cLog_connect();
    }

    void log(const std::string &message){    //entry point
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
        cLog_write(cLog, message);
        }

    ~LoggerWrapper(){        //destructor
        cLog_close(cLog);
        delete cLog;
    }
protected:
     cLog_Logger *cLog;
     std::mutex mutex ;
} ;
```

Comment: I don't think the mutex as non-static class member will solve problem. Imagine, op create 2 LoggerWrapper instances in 2 different threads. Boom!

Comment: @marom, it is a good point to move 'cLog_close(cLog)' to the destructor, my consideration was to close the connection as soon as the log writing is done, although I am not sure whether it makes sense.

Comment: @marom, your speculation on "thread safety" is correct, the API doesn't have mechanism to avoid synchronization problem. Your solution seems to be correct, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no it's not. At first, I think there must be `free()` instead of `delete`, because it's `c` api.
What you doing can give your resource-leak-free program, but not thread-safe. RAII is for avoiding leak of resources.
There is straightforward but inefficient way to wrap your API for thread safe to add static mutex in your RAII class.

```
#include <mutex>

class LoggerWrapper{

public:
    LoggerWrapper() : l(globalLock);
    {              //constructor
        cLog= cLog_connect();
    }

    void log(const std::string &message){    //entry point
        cLog_write(cLog, message);
        cLog_close(cLog);
        }

    ~LoggerWrapper(){        //destructor
        free(cLog); // I think here must be free(), but not sure
    }
protected:
    cLog_Logger *cLog;
    static std::mutex globalLock;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l;
}

std::mutex LoggerWrapper::globalLock;
```

Comment: thanks! As we are discussing the c++ wrapper class, I think ree() and delete do not pose significant differences.

Comment: Could you please explain the usage of the lock_guard member? the member 'l' is assigned in initialization, but doesn't do anything later.

Comment: @ulyssis2, lock_guard is RAII template, which acquires mutex lock in constructor and releases mutex lock in its destructor. While lock_guard exists it holds mutex in locked state.

Comment: @ulyssis2, free() or delete is very significant. If you get pointer to memory from c api, it obviously was obtained from malloc(). So you must dispose it only with free(), not delete, or, c api could provide special function to free connected log. Even if with delete all works, it does not mean code is right.